# Google drive SDK 2.0 throws error 400 Bad Request

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've been fighting with Google Drive API for Android for more than 50 hours now, and have not come one inch closer. From my understanding, there are 1001 ways to access Google drive (Google Docs API, REST & Google Drive SDK v2). I'm using Google Drive SDK v2. I want want to access Google Drive to upload jpeg files. Platform, Android 2.2+.

What I've tried:

- Using the recently released SDK:
  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API
- I've watched the Google I/O sesssion, but the most important part (how to create a Drive object using your Client ID & Client Secret) was left out:
  https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/705/
- I have created multiple keys on https://code.google.com/apis/console. The last one I've created (and tested with) was created using "Create another client ID..." -> "Installed Application" -> "Android". I've used the key in the ~/.android/debug.keystore.
- I've also tried to create a key for an "Other" (instead of Android/iOS) installed app, but this gives me a Client ID and Client secret. It seems like the Drive object does not accept a client secret.
- Where the code says "1234567890-abcdefghij123klmnop.apps.googleusercontent.com", I've tried to use both "API key" and the "Client ID", both gave the same error.

My code:

```
Account account = AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByType(
        "com.google")[0];

String token;
try {
    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account.name, "oauth2:"
            + DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
} catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
    context.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), ASK_PERMISSION);
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    return;
} catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
    return;
}

HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
final String tokenCopy = token;
b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
        driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
        driveRequest
                .setKey("1234567890-abcdefghij123klmnop.apps.googleusercontent.com");
        driveRequest.setOauthToken(tokenCopy);
    }
});

final Drive drive = b.build();
FileList files;
try {
    files = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType=text/plain").execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // throws HTTP 400
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}
```

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to add a file from Android to Google Drive via the Web App ONLY based API and not through your own server?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes, directly from Android to Google Drive. I'm using the library from the following link. Is that Web App only? From my understanding the Google I/O video talks about this API, isn't it? What's the recommended way to upload a file from Android?  http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, your error is in the query parameter `q`. The correct syntax for your `q` parameter is

```
files = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType='text/plain'").execute();
```

and not :

```
files = drive.files().list().setQ("mimeType=text/plain").execute();
```

Looking at your code, you are fully authenticated and your request is failing because of this syntax error.